# Using python unable to load CSV file into MySql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I was trying to load trans_dt into cmdels table. but it throws syntax error. How to add local variable into table. The Local variable name is newDate

```
import mysql.connector
config = {
'user':'root',
'password':'password',
'host':'127.0.0.1',
'database':'nse'
}
conn= mysql.connector.connect(**config)
c=conn.cursor()
def insertRows(fileName,c):
    delimiter=r','
    dateString=r'%d-%b-%Y'
    file=fileName.split("/")[-1]

    if file.startswith("MTO"):
        newDate=new_Date(file)

        c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmdels fields terminated by %s 
        ignore 4 lines(recno,srno,symbol,series,qtytrd,qtydel,qtyper,trans_dt) 
        SET trans_dt=(@trans_dt,%s)", (fileName, delimiter,newDate))

localExtractFilePath="/Users/data/nse"

import os

def new_Date(s):
return s[4:-4]

for file in os.listdir(localExtractFilePath):
    if file.endswith(".DAT"):
        insertRows(localExtractFilePath+"/"+file,c)
        print "Loaded file "+file+" into database"
       conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the full trace so that we can easily spot the line?

Comment: line 23, in insertRows
    c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmdels fields terminated by %s ignore 4 lines(recno,srno,symbol,series,qtytrd,qtydel,qtyper,trans_dt) SET trans_dt=(@trans_dt,%s)", (fileName, delimiter,newDate))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))

Comment: Add that to the question in a code block so we can read it more easily!

Comment: ...and include the whole trace, including the error line.

Comment: Part of your problem is that single quoted string literals can't span lines. You should have some sort of EOL error there. You could add quotes at the end and beginning of each line in the execute for that.

Comment: if am not adding trans_dt, it works well.  c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmdels fields terminated by %s
    ignore 4 lines(recno,srno,symbol,series,qtytrd,qtydel,qtyper,trans_dt)", 
    (fileName, delimiter,newDate))

Comment: That's still not very readable. If you post it in your question as a code block like your code, its easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Single quoted string literals can't span newlines. You can use triple-quoted strings (`"""Load data..."""`) but you end up with extra whitespace and newlines in the string, which can cause their own problems. A good option is to end each line with an end quote and let python concatenate them in the compilation step

```
   c.execute("Load data local infile %s into table cmdels fields terminated by %s"
    " ignore 4 lines(recno,srno,symbol,series,qtytrd,qtydel,qtyper,trans_dt)" 
    " SET trans_dt=(@trans_dt,%s)", (fileName, delimiter,newDate))
```